# What is the best way to format a button macro?

Tags: macro

I'm looking for a solution on the best way to setup a macro for buttons that are defined in a matrix fieldtype.

My current code works fine but it really isn't that DRY and I feel it could be made better.

I first import my button macro in a main template:

```
{% import "_includes/buttons" as buttons %}
```

Then my code for the matrix field is:

```
{% for block in cube.button %}
   {{ buttons.span(block.buttonType, block.buttonText, block.buttonColour, block.buttonSize, block.fullWidthButton, cube.linkUrl) }}
{% endfor %}
```

And now my not so DRY button macro

```
{% macro span(type, text, colour, size, fullWidth, url) -%}
    <span class="btn {{ type }} {{ colour }} {{ size }}{% if fullWidth %} btn-block{% endif %}">{{ text }}</span>
{% endmacro -%}

{% macro a(type, text, colour, size, fullWidth, url) -%}
    <a href="{{ url }}" class="btn {{ type }} {{ colour }} {{ size }}{% if fullWidth %} btn-block{% endif %}">{{ text }}</a>
{% endmacro -%}

{% macro button(type, text, colour, size, fullWidth, url) -%}
    <button class="btn {{ type }} {{ colour }} {{ size }}{% if fullWidth %} btn-block{% endif %}">{{ text }}</button>
{% endmacro -%}

{% macro submit(type, text, colour, size, fullWidth, url) -%}
    <input type="submit" class="btn {{ type }} {{ colour }} {{ size }}{% if fullWidth %} btn-block{% endif %}" value="{{ text }}"/>
{% endmacro -%}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could factor out that repeated `class=...` like so:

```
{% macro _btnClass(type, colour, size, fullWidth) %}
    class="btn {{ type }} {{ colour }} {{ size }}{% if fullWidth %} btn-block{% endif %}"
{% endmacro %}

{% macro span(type, text, colour, size, fullWidth, url) -%}
{% import _self as self %}
    <span {{ self._btnClass(type, colour, size, fullWidth) }}>{{ text }}</span>
{% endmacro -%}
```

It is not clear from your question how you decide which buttons macro to call. Perhaps that code needs to be made DRYer.

Comment: Updated question with the macro import: which is just one file that holds all the different macros.

Comment: You must be calling buttons.a and buttons.button and buttons.submit somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Ah you are absolutely right. Thought I would be able to set that as a var and use that. Turns out that doesn't work. :(